# Why is my image in div tag with class parallax not showing?

Tags: html, materialize

so I am working on my portfolio and I am using Materialize CSS. I am trying to give my image a parallax effect but the image in between my div tags with class parallax is not working. Can someone please help me figure it out? I will be really grateful for the help.

Comment: can you show us some code? preferably create a working example on eg. jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

In order to work parallax with MaterializeCSS.

1.Make sure to place parallax images inside parallax-container and parallax.
2.Import jQuery before materialize.js.
3.Call the the parallax  javaScript at the end.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parallax-container">
   <div class="parallax"><img src="images/parallax1.jpg"></div>
  </div>


  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script> 
//Initialise 
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.parallax').parallax();
      }); 
</script>
</body>
```

[Materialize Parallax Codepen](https://codepen.io/jasjashim/pen/PQEoaM)

Comment: VERY important to import jQuery BEFORE materialize. Thank you!!! Can't find this tip anywhere else!